# libgdx collision with line and polygon (Intersector)

Tags: java, libgdx, collision-detection, intersection

My `libgdx` game has a laser and I want to know if the beam hits it's target.

I had some trouble with the function **(always getting true)** so I made a very simple test and I still get true!

Did I miss something?

Why is this function returning true?

```
if(Intersector.intersectLinePolygon(new Vector2(100, 100), new Vector2(200, 100), new Polygon(new float[] {0, 0, 5, 0, 5, 5}))) {
    System.out.println("true");
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got caught by this when I first used Intersector too.

The `intersectLinePolygon()` method works on a line that extends infinitely, and not just between the two points you specify.

Use the `intersectSegmentPolygon()` method which does what you want...

```
if(Intersector.intersectSegmentPolygon(new Vector2(100, 100), new Vector2(200, 100), new Polygon(new float[] {0, 0, 5, 0, 5, 5}))) {
    System.out.println("true");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That solved the problem and i get the difference between those functions, but wouldn't it still be false because even with an infinite line, it would never intersect in my example?

Comment: It would intersect at (0, 0)